# Implementing IP restrictions in Go gin

Tags: go, ip, authorization, go-gin

I'm setting up a small demo app I'd like only accessible from my home IP address for now, and maybe a small set of technical people I'll coordinate and share with.

I looked through the readme here, but couldn't find:
https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin

---what's the canonical, minimal example for how to limit access on an app to only particular IP addresses in gin?

(Also, any reason this is a particularly unsafe idea in 2018?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I answer your question,  I would like to say that it would likely be more practical to limit access to the app using firewall rules rather than in the program itself, but I digress.

To answer your question, after looking through the gin [godoc reference](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin) I found that the [context struct](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ClientIP) contains a `ClientIp()` method that:

> implements a best effort algorithm to return the real client IP, it parses X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For in order to work properly with reverse-proxies such us: nginx or haproxy. Use X-Forwarded-For before X-Real-Ip as nginx uses X-Real-Ip with the proxy's IP.

Therefore, if you are set on doing the IP filtering in the app, you could filter based on the value returned by that method.

Using the basic example given on the Github page:

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

var Whitelist []string = []string{"1.2.3.4"}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        whitelisted := false
        for _, v := range Whitelist {
            if v == c.ClientIP() {
                whitelisted = true
            }
        }
        if whitelisted {
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
            })
        } else {
            c.JSON(403, gin.H{})
        }
    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

Comment: The tip about firewall is completely true, completely duh, and completely helpful.  Thanks for that as well as the great application-specific answer.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!